# Arabic Date To English‎ date conversion

Tags: php

i am searching last couple of days that How to Convert Arabic Date in To English Date ,
e.g    1435/05/02 Convert To 2014/03/03 ? but no result i founded so help me Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some googling, I found this class: [Source code here](http://pastebin.com/QTbJK8C1)

The usage is simple

```
include 'class.php';
$DateConv = new Hijri_GregorianConvert;
$format="YYYY/MM/DD";
$date="1400/03/22"; // Arabic date here
echo $DateConv->HijriToGregorian($date,$format);
```

Comment: what "class.php" supposed to do here?

Comment: include the class? whatever he's gonna name it? @DonCallisto

Comment: what class? why are you including that line into your code?

Comment: "With some googling, I found this class: Source code here" @DonCallisto, you know... PHP Class?

Comment: Sorry didn't notice the link above

Answer (score 0):

I found those two webpages with a converter:

http://www.islamicity.com/PrayerTimes/hijriconverter1aPartner.htm

and

http://www.islamicfinder.org/dateConversion.php

They are both based on clientside JavaScript to make the conversion. So go to the pages and chose "show source code" in your browser.